# Elasticsearch data path on a Vagrant shared directory

Tags: elasticsearch, filesystems, vagrant, virtualbox

I have Elasticsearch installed on a Vagrant machine with a Windows host running VirtualBox. It runs okay when I use it with the default data path, but if I try to switch the path to a synced Vagrant folder, it throws an `ElasticsearchIllegalStateException`.

I am running with the command line

```
elasticsearch  -Des.path.logs=/shared/logs -Des.path.data=/shared/data
```

Where `/shared` is the mount point for my synced folder in Vagrant.

The error I'm getting is:

```
[2015-07-28 14:15:05,005][WARN ][bootstrap                ] Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK (ulimit).
[2015-07-28 14:15:05,104][INFO ][node                     ] [Caliban] version[1.7.0], pid[1832], build[929b973/2015-07-16T14:31:07Z]
[2015-07-28 14:15:05,105][INFO ][node                     ] [Caliban] initializing ...
[2015-07-28 14:15:05,390][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Caliban] loaded [], sites []
{1.7.0}: Initialization Failed ...
- ElasticsearchIllegalStateException[Failed to created node environment]
    FileSystemException[/shared: Not a directory]
```

If I run this using a regular non-synced directories, then it works fine, e.g.

```
elasticsearch  -Des.path.logs=/home/vagrant -Des.path.data=/home/vagrant
```

Results in:

```
[2015-07-28 14:20:27,598][WARN ][bootstrap                ] Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK (ulimit).
[2015-07-28 14:20:27,693][INFO ][node                     ] [Madame MacEvil] version[1.7.0], pid[1989], build[929b973/2015-07-16T14:31:07Z]
[2015-07-28 14:20:27,694][INFO ][node                     ] [Madame MacEvil] initializing ...
[2015-07-28 14:20:27,958][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Madame MacEvil] loaded [], sites []
[2015-07-28 14:20:28,020][INFO ][env                      ] [Madame MacEvil] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root)]], net usable_space [33.6gb], net total_space [37.9gb], types [ext4]
[2015-07-28 14:20:31,951][INFO ][node                     ] [Madame MacEvil] initialized
[2015-07-28 14:20:31,951][INFO ][node                     ] [Madame MacEvil] starting ...
[2015-07-28 14:20:32,053][INFO ][transport                ] [Madame MacEvil] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.2.15:9300]}
[2015-07-28 14:20:32,074][INFO ][discovery                ] [Madame MacEvil] elasticsearch/18ZhO5W8SwWwJve7KBdV5g
[2015-07-28 14:20:35,859][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Madame MacEvil] new_master [Madame MacEvil][18ZhO5W8SwWwJve7KBdV5g][localhost.localdomain][inet[/10.0.2.15:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-07-28 14:20:35,890][INFO ][http                     ] [Madame MacEvil] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.2.15:9200]}
[2015-07-28 14:20:35,894][INFO ][node                     ] [Madame MacEvil] started
[2015-07-28 14:20:35,919][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Madame MacEvil] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

I pulled the logs for a failed initialization and it had the following Java exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalStateException: Failed to created node environment
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:245)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /shared: Not a directory
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileStore.readAttributes(UnixFileStore.java:111)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileStore.getTotalSpace(UnixFileStore.java:118)
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.fs.JmxFsProbe.getFSInfo(JmxFsProbe.java:61)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.maybeLogPathDetails(NodeEnvironment.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:176)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:165)
    ... 4 more
```

Is this a known issue with VirtualBox + Vagrant and Elasticsearch?

Comment: Your windows folders have all access ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

`sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/`